# How to refresh Taskbar Thumbnails after Aero was turned off and on again?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, aero, thumbnails

I use the radmin remote software that turns off Aero when it runs. When I exit, Aero turns back on, but all of my taskbar thumbnails are gone until I manually restore each window – a royal pain!

Is there an app or command that can refresh the taskbar thumbnails, say on a single click?